# Formatted string as datatype

Tags: c#, types, format

I have a format for certain Ids and I'd rather have a custom datatype for them rather than store them as a string.
How is this done in C#?
Is this a good idea in the first place?

An example below should explain what I mean:

Id format (D for digit, C for alphabet char): CCDDDD

```
public ItemId id { get; set; }
...  
public class ItemId {
// somehow declare the format here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap a class around your string ID which takes a input string as constructor parameter. This way you can also put methods in your class to provide extra functionality etc, and always have the formatting in one place. Simple example:

```
   public class ItemId
   {
        private string _id;

        public string ID
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                //do some formatting here
                _id= value;
            }
        }

        public ItemId(string id)
        {
            ID = id
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            //do some extra formatting here if needed
            return Value;
        }
   }
```

Because you can only manipulate the real ID through the public setter, you can have your formatting and validation logic in one single place. Hope this helps you a bit. I think it's a good idea because a class ItemId is more meaningful then just a string, and also a lot easier to extend or change functionality in the future.

For example you can check the input with regex, and throw your own exception if input does not match your format. That gives you meaningful information at runtime. Also you can add xml comment to the public setter, so if you or anyone uses it, it's clear what the ID should look like.

Comment: or maybe use the ToString() function to output the formatted string!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by implementing your extensions, which I would prefer than overriding ToString method.

For Example

```
public static class Extension
{
     public static string MyFormat(this string str)
     {
         //do sth with your string
         return str;
     }
}
```

And you can use this extension like

```
string abc = "";
abc.MyFormat();
```